# How to convert primitive long datatype to Class type for Class.getMethod(methodName, Class...);

Tags: java, methods, reflection

How can i pass a datatype of type long as a param for method which is accepting arbitrary param Class...

I am actually trying to get the reflection of a method from the below class.

```
 Class Fun(){public Object getBox(long boxId, String boxName){}}
```

Trying to access this method using below Code.

`Class clazz = new fun().getClass();
String str = "Welcome";
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("getBox",new Long(22).getClass, str.getClass());`

Iam getting the below exception when i try accessing the method name for invoking.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
```

How to pass a long and a string variable for parametertypes in the below method signature.

```
public Method getMethod(String name,
               Class<?>... parameterTypes)
                 throws NoSuchMethodException,
                        SecurityException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java considers `long` and `Long` as two different types. The former is a primitive type while the latter is a reference type. You need the `Class` object of the former.

You can get the class of `long` by doing `long.class`. Actually, you can get the `Class` object of any class by doing `ClassName.class`.

Therefore, your code can be rewritten like this:

```
Class<fun> clazz = fun.class;
Method method = clazz.getMethod("getBox",long.class, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `primitive.class` for primitives - in your example:

```
Method method = clazz.getMethod("getBox", long.class, String.class);
```